# Strange behavior of Azure Application Insights when an exception happens

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have ASP.NET Web API application that is deployed on Azure App Service. For it I use the free plan. Also I turned on Application Insights. I noticed the app devours about 1.7 GB memory when an exception happens and Application Insights is turned on. Due to this the quotas are exceeded. When I turn off Application Insights and an exception raises, all works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have [Snapshot Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger) enabled which sometimes creates a memory dump when an exception is tracked by ApplicationInsights. The feature is not intended to be used on the free plan.

To disable it go to the "Application Insights" page inside the App service and disable "Snapshot Debugger".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it and write the result.

Comment: Thank you a lot. As I understood, you were absolutely right.